# starting with GtkExtra for using GtkPlot

Tags: c, gtk3

i want to use GtkExtra for GtkPlot as it is deprecated in gtk+3. I downloaded gtkextra-3.0.5.tar.gz but where to keep this folder after extracting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it. Look for a pre-packaged variant for your particular operating system, the download you have might be the source code which is not needed. **Update** It seems Ubuntu-flavored distributions have (as you say) deprecated all of GtkExtra, which seems a bit troublesome.

[This page](http://blog.laczik.org/gpsim-ubuntu-and-the-case-of-the-missing-gui/) has instructions on how to compile it from source, it doesn't sound very complicated although a few source modifications are given.

When it's properly installed, [the manual](http://gtkextra.sourceforge.net/cms/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=20) says you will be able to use `pkg-config` to get `CFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` and so on, just as with the rest of GTK+.

Comment: but how to install gtkExtra?

Comment: @user3497983 What platform (operating system) are you on? It controls how software is installed.

Comment: Xubuntu 13.04 is the operating system